# Testing gRPC with ngrok fails due to connection forcefully terminated

Tags: grpc, ngrok

I'm having some issues with exposing a gRPC server through ngrok.

I've followed and downloaded the demo code from [here](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/dart/).

Connection through localhost is fine, but connecting through ngrok leads me to the following error:

> Caught error: gRPC Error (2, HTTP/2 error: Connection error: Connection is being forcefully terminated. (errorCode: 10))

here's the tunnel config I'm using for ngrok in my `~/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml` file:

```
tunnels:
  grpc:
    proto: http
    addr: 8080
    bind_tls: true
    region: eu
    inspect: true
```

And this is what I've done so far:

1. `dart bin/server.dart`
2. `ngrok grpc`
3. edit the `lib/src/client.dart` to use the `forwarding` url from ngrok
4. `dart bin/client.dart`

Though the server is listening on 8080, the client is trying to connect to ngrok's url on standard port 443 for https.

I'm thinking about something with HTTP2 (which gRPC depends on), but according to [this](https://ngrok.com/whatsnew) ngrok should support it (I'm running version `2.3.35`).

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out `ngrok` didn't perform well with the `http` option.

Switching to `proto:tcp` solved my problem.

I suppose that's because ngrok expects something not provided by gRPC when selecting the `proto: http`!

Comment: any chance you could share the complete ngrok.yml file with the tunnel spec you're using for gRPC? I've tried changing proto:http to proto:tcp in the example you've provided, but can't get it to work - if you have a complete working config I'd love to see it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I don't know if my current .yaml is consistent since it's old and I might have used ngrok for other things after this questions. My current .yaml is basically the same of the one in my question but without the `bind_tls` line (just delete it). Reading my answer, though, hints me that other than removing `bind_tls ` you should change `proto:http` to `proto:tcp`!

Answer (score 5):

To be more specific

ngrok.yml

```
tunnels:
  grpc:
    proto: tcp
    addr: 5001
    inspect: false
```

after configuring ngrok.yml, hit `ngrok start grpc` in terminal

you will get an address like this `tcp://0.tcp.in.ngrok.io:15048`

use `0.tcp.in.ngrok.io:15048` to check responses.

I use [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download) to check grpc responses.

if you don't want to configure ngrok.yml, you can use  `./ngrok tcp 5001` as an alternative option